# returning a reference vs the type

Tags: c++

I was looking over some code, in a textbook and they wrote:

```
Vector3 &operator =(const Vector3 &a) {
    x = a.x; y = a.y; z = a.z;
    return *this;
}
```

Does the following code produce the same, returning the type, not a reference to it(they both run):

```
Vector3 operator =(const Vector3 &a) {
    x = a.x; y = a.y; z = a.z;
    return *this;
}
```

my question: what is the difference between the two?

thanks
daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector3 a, b;
(a = b).x = 3;
```

In this code, `a.x` should end up with the value of `3`. In the second example you give, that won't happen.

Comment: this link: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/ helped clarify this point

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 b(1,2,3);
Vector3 a;

(a = b).x += 2.0;

Print(a.x);
```

If you use operator returning refernce, above code should print 3.0

In case of operator returning value it would print 1.0